# Filtering by object-descendants RATIONAL DOORS 9.6

Tags: ibm-doors

Is it possible to set the filter that display only every chosen object descendants or create a new view to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If by "chosen" you mean that the user selects one or more objects (e.g. using shift-click) and then the descendants shall magically appear below each selected object without any further user interaction, the answer is "no".

But "yes", you could write a DXL script, add it e.g. to the "User" menu, let the user select objects and start the menu entry. The script could create a Skip list with all selected objects, using sth like

```
Skip sk = create
Object o
Module m = current
for o in m do {
    if isSelected o then put (sk, o, o)
}
```

and then create a new view with the columns you need and use `accept` and `reject` to fill the view, like

```
for o in entire m do {
    if (find (sk, o)) {
        accept o
    } else {
        reject o
    }
}
```

Edit: forgot the descendants :-| So, after adding all objects from the skip to the view you will need a recursive function that displays the sub objects for every displayed object. Something along the following lines:

```
void recursive_show_objects(Object o) {
    Object o2
    for o2 in o do {
        accept o2
        recursive_show_objects (o2)
    }
}
for o in sk do {
    recursive_show_objects (o)
}
```

Comment: of course, these are only snippets, the whole script will be a bit longer :)

Comment: once you accept objects found in skip list and before applying recursive function, use statement `current = m`